How to transfer a Bitcoin-core wallet to new computer
what is the best way to transfer my Bitcoincore wallet? it has a wallet.dat backup file but what do i do with it? do i simply download the app on the ne PC and copy that file onto it?

This question is similar to: Restore encrypted wallet. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
